# Get list photo when setting new permission `Limit` in ios 14

Tags: ios, swift, photokit

I use code for get list image

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)
return PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: options)
```

But in permission `Limit` in ios 14 this will get all image.
[image]

Just get only limit photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. It only occurs in the simulator. You can try it on a real device. It's probably a bug in the simulator.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you. It's bug in the simulator.